# How to add custom input field in orangehrm (add vacancy section)

Tags: php, symfony, orangehrm

I need to add custom filed textbox(skill) in add vacancy section in orangehrm.

I am trying following code.It show text filed in the form but not add in the database.

**orangehrm-3.1\symfony\plugins\orangehrmRecruitmentPlugin\modules\recruitment\templates\addJobVacancySuccess.php**

**Code:-**

```
<?php
use_stylesheet(plugin_web_path('orangehrmRecruitmentPlugin', 'css/addJobVacancySuccess'));
use_javascript(plugin_web_path('orangehrmRecruitmentPlugin', 'js/addJobVacancySuccess'));
?>

<div class="box" id="addJobVacancy">

    <div class="head">
        <h1><?php echo isset($vacancyId) ? __('Edit Job Vacancy') : __('Add Job Vacancy'); ?></h1>
    </div>

    <div class="inner">
        <?php include_partial('global/flash_messages'); ?>
        <form name="frmAddJobVacancy" id="frmAddJobVacancy" method="post">

            <?php echo $form['_csrf_token']; ?>
            <?php echo $form["hiringManagerId"]->render(); 

            ?>
            <fieldset>
                <ol>

                    <li>
                        <?php echo $form['jobTitle']->renderLabel(__('Job Title') . ' <em>*</em>'); ?>
                        <?php echo $form['jobTitle']->render(array("maxlength" => 50)); ?>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <?php echo $form['name']->renderLabel(__('Vacancy Name') . ' <em>*</em>'); ?>
                        <?php echo $form['name']->render(array("maxlength" => 50)); ?>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <?php echo $form['hiringManager']->renderLabel(__('Hiring Manager') . ' <em>*</em>'); ?>
                        <?php echo $form['hiringManager']->render(array("maxlength" => 100)); ?>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <?php echo $form['noOfPositions']->renderLabel(__('Number of Positions')); ?>
                        <?php echo $form['noOfPositions']->render(array("maxlength" => 2)); ?>
                    </li>
                    <li class="largeTextBox">
                        <?php echo $form['description']->renderLabel(__('Description')); ?>
                        <?php echo $form['description']->render(array("cols" => 30, "rows" => 9)); ?>
                    </li>
                    <li>

                         <?php echo $form['skill']->renderLabel(__('Vacancy Skills') . ' <em>*</em>'); ?>
                        <?php echo $form['skill']->render(array("maxlength" => 50)); ?>                     
                        </li>

                    <li>
                        <?php echo $form['status']->renderLabel(__('Active')); ?>
                        <?php echo $form['status']->render(); ?>
                    </li>

                    <li class="labelRight">
                        <?php echo $form['publishedInFeed']->render(); ?>
                        <?php echo $form['publishedInFeed']->renderLabel(__('Publish in RSS feed(1) and web page(2)')); ?>
                    </li>

                    <?php include_component('core', 'ohrmPluginPannel', array('location' => 'add_layout_before_navigation_bar_1')) ?>

                    <li class="required">
                        <em>*</em> <?php echo __(CommonMessages::REQUIRED_FIELD); ?>
                    </li>
                    <li class="helpText">
                        1 : <?php echo __('RSS Feed URL') ?> : <?php echo link_to(null, 'recruitmentApply/jobs.rss', array('absolute' => true, 'target' => '_new')); ?>
                    </li>
                    <li class="helpText">
                        2 : <?php echo __('Web Page URL') ?> : <?php echo link_to(null, 'recruitmentApply/jobs.html', array('absolute' => true, 'target' => '_new')); ?>
                    </li>

                </ol>
                <p>
                    <?php if (isset($vacancyId)) { ?>
                        <input type="button" class="savebutton" name="btnSave" id="btnSave" value="<?php echo __("Edit"); ?>"/>
                        <input type="button" class="backbutton" name="btnBack" id="btnBack" value="<?php echo __("Back"); ?>"/>
                    <?php } else { ?>
                        <input type="button" class="savebutton" name="btnSave" id="btnSave"value="<?php echo __("Save"); ?>"/>
                    <?php } ?>
                </p>
            </fieldset>
        </form>
    </div>
    <?php
    if (isset($vacancyId)) {
        echo include_component('recruitment', 'attachments', array('id' => $vacancyId, 'screen' => JobVacancy::TYPE));
    }
    ?>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
    var hiringManagers = <?php echo str_replace('&#039;', "'", $form->getHiringManagerListAsJson()) ?> ;
    var hiringManagersArray = eval(hiringManagers);
    var lang_typeForHints = '<?php echo __("Type for hints") . "..."; ?>';
    var lang_negativeAmount = "<?php echo __("Should be a positive number"); ?>";
    var lang_tooLargeAmount = "<?php echo __("Should be less than %amount%", array("%amount%" => '99')); ?>";
    var lang_jobTitleRequired = '<?php echo __(ValidationMessages::REQUIRED); ?>';
    var lang_vacancyNameRequired = '<?php echo __(ValidationMessages::REQUIRED); ?>';
    var lang_enterAValidEmployeeName = "<?php echo __(ValidationMessages::INVALID); ?>";
    var lang_nameExistmsg = "<?php echo __("Already exists"); ?>";
    var vacancyNames = <?php echo $form->getVacancyList(); ?>;
    var vacancyNameList = eval(vacancyNames);
    var lang_edit = "<?php echo __("Edit"); ?>";
    var lang_save = "<?php echo __("Save"); ?>";
    var lang_cancel = "<?php echo __("Cancel"); ?>";
    var lang_back = "<?php echo __("Back"); ?>";
    var linkForAddJobVacancy = "<?php echo url_for('recruitment/addJobVacancy'); ?>";
    var lang_descriptionLength = "<?php echo __(ValidationMessages::TEXT_LENGTH_EXCEEDS, array('%amount%' => 40000)) ?>";
    var backBtnUrl = '<?php echo url_for('recruitment/viewJobVacancy?'); ?>';
    var backCancelUrl = '<?php echo url_for('recruitment/addJobVacancy?'); ?>';
<?php if (isset($vacancyId)) { ?>
        var vacancyId = '<?php echo $vacancyId; ?>';
<?php } else { ?>
        var vacancyId = "";
<?php } ?>
    //]]>
</script>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Try this..**

**1)You need to create filed name (skill) in your table.**

**2)Add following lines to orangehrm-3.1\symfony\lib\model\doctrine\orangehrmRecruitmentPlugin\base\BaseJobVacancy.class.php**

```
 Inside public function setTableDefinition(){}
   $this->hasColumn('skill', 'string', 100, array(
             'type' => 'string',
             'length' => 100,
             ));
```

**3)Add following lines to orangehrm-3.1\symfony\plugins\orangehrmRecruitmentPlugin\modules\recruitment\templates\addJobVacancySuccess.php**

```
Inside the form following lines

  <li>                       
    <?php echo $form['skill']->renderLabel(__('Vacancy Skills') . ' <em>*</em>'); ?>
    <?php echo $form['skill']->render(array("maxlength" => 50)); ?>                     
    </li>
```

**4)Add following lines to orangehrm-3.1\symfony\plugins\orangehrmRecruitmentPlugin\lib\form\AddJobVacancyForm.php**

```
Inside Widgetarray like following code

   $this->setWidgets(array(
            'jobTitle' => new sfWidgetFormSelect(array('choices' => $jobTitleList)),
            'name' => new sfWidgetFormInputText(),
            'hiringManager' => new sfWidgetFormInputText(),
            ......
            .....
            'skill' => new sfWidgetFormInputText(),
            ));

    Inside setValidatorsarray like following code

     $this->setValidators(array(
            'jobTitle' => new sfValidatorString(array('required' => true)),
            'name' => new sfValidatorString(array('required' => true)),
            'hiringManager' => new sfValidatorString(array('required' => true)),
            .....
            .....
            ....
            'skill' => new sfValidatorString(array('required' => true)),
             ));

    Inside following code in if loop "if (isset($vacancy) && $vacancy != null) {}"

    $this->setDefault('skill', $vacancy->getSkill());

    Inside save() function add following following code

        $jobVacancy->skill = $this->getValue('skill');
```

Answer (score 0):

I am agree with Deena's answer. I created a new field in Salary section just like that.

Checkout following link

http://forum.orangehrm.com/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=18413&sid=fa8d38e5b5825097a6299ef534636c93