# Adding Custom Fields In orengehrm

Tags: custom-fields, orangehrm

I would like just to ask if anybody there has a knowledge in increasing the available custom fields in orangehrm. The default would be 10 fields but what I need is more than 15 fields to meet the requirement. I have tried to change the  MAX_FIELD_NUM into 15 from the file PluginCustomField.class.php. The problem is that it still accept only 10 fieldd.

Please anyone there help me. Thanks a lot.

Comment: which module are you working like vacancy and candidates?

Comment: I am working under the pim module. Under the configuration tab.

Comment: Try this...http://stackoverflow.com/q/27780354/2960703

Answer (score 0):

Instead to using custom field, why do not you create specific field in specific section. For example create a salary review field in salary section,
Checkout following link

http://forum.orangehrm.com/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=18413&sid=fa8d38e5b5825097a6299ef534636c93

Answer (score 0):

You need to change all this positions.

There where you see Cutsomfield 10 as last, you need to add more. and instead of 10 put number you want.

```
/dbscript/dbscript-1.sql

/symfony/apps/orangehrm/lib/model/admin/dao/CustomExportDao.php

/symfony/data/sql/schema.sql

/symfony/lib/filter/doctrine/base/BaseEmployeeFormFilter.class.php

/symfony/lib/form/doctrine/base/BaseEmployeeForm.class.php

/symfony/lib/model/doctrine/orangehrmPimPlugin/base/BaseEmployee.class.php

/symfony/plugins/orangehrmPimPlugin/config/doctrine/schema.yml

/symfony/plugins/orangehrmPimPlugin/lib/dao/EmployeeDao.php

/symfony/plugins/orangehrmPimPlugin/lib/dao/CustomFieldConfigurationDao.php

/symfony/plugins/orangehrmPimPlugin/lib/model/doctrine/PluginCustomField.class.p
hp
```